# When are two Abelian p-groups with the same character isomorphic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups, direct-sum, p-groups

Definition 2.6 of [this journal paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0168007208001863) defines a notion called “character” for Abelian $p$-groups:

> 1. $\oplus_\alpha H$ denotes the direct sum of $\alpha$ copies of $H$ where $\alpha\leq\omega$.
> 2. If $A=\oplus_{i<\omega}\mathbb(Z)(p^{n_i})$, then the *character* of $A$ is $\chi(A)=\left\{\langle n,k\rangle:card(\left\{i:n_i=n\right\})\geq k\right\}$.
> 3. If $G = A\oplus\oplus_\alpha\mathbb{Z}(p^\infty)$ for some $\alpha\leq\omega$ and some $A$ as in part 2, then $\chi(G)=\chi(A)$

Where $\mathbb{Z}(p^n)$ denotes the cyclic group of $p^n$ and $\mathbb{Z}(p^{\infty})$ denotes the [Prüfer $p$-group](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pr%C3%BCfer_group).

Now suppose you have proven that two Abelian $p$-groups $G$ and $H$ have the same character.  Then my question is, does that get you any closer to proving that $G$ and $H$ are isomorphic?  If so, what do you need to prove in addition to that to prove that they’re isomorphic?

Does the fact that they have the same character restrict how much their [Ulm sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Height_(abelian_group)#Ulm%27s_theorem) can differ?

Comment: Well, note that $G=\mathbb{Z}(p^{\infty})$ and $H=\mathbb{Z}(p^{\infty})\oplus\mathbb{Z}(p^{\infty})$ have the same character, but are not isomrophic.

Comment: Yeah, I’m certainly not claiming that any two Abelian p-groups with the same character are isomorphic.  I’m just trying to find out if there’s something you can add to having the same character that implies that two Abelian p-groups are isomorphic.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, same character gives you that the reduced parts are isomorphic and have the same Ulm invariants, and since your groups are, by construction, countable, it follows that they only differ in their divisible parts, which must be a direct sum of copies of the Prufer $p$-group, and the divisible part is completely determined by how many such direct factors there are. So you should end up that they just differ in their divisible part, and that difference is straightforward to quantify. But I would want to work through all the details carefully.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin OK, if you work through the details and post that as an answer I’d be happy to accept it.